# Display Top category only in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have some posts belonging to multiple categories. I have defined a Top Category for each of them and I would like to display this Top Category only on my category page. Unfortunately it shows ALL the categories attributed. (eg. first post on this category page: https://www.la-strada.net/rubrique/muzik-zak/ ).
A developper provided a function that should help but it was a long shot…

https://gist.github.com/LucasDemea/afa5d58c8e9ed0d71b7b2523d84bcce9

My sentiment is that the theme used (Qode Bridge) uses its own terms for naming WP elements, so the code does not call them properly.
Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

The script you linked is actually working, but you have to call it on the front-end.

If you want a more straight forward way to fetch them inside a loop you can do the following:

```
<?php
if( have_posts() ): // ... loop starting
  while( have_posts() ): the_post();

    // ... get our post categories
    $categories = get_the_category(); // ... get post categories
    foreach( $categories as $category ) {
      if ( $category->parent == 0 ) { // ... if the category has no parent
        echo '<p>' . $category->cat_name . '</p>'; // ... display the category name
      };
    };

    the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );

  endwhile;
endif; // ... loop ending
?>
```

| Function | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `get_the_category` | [Retrieves post categories.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) |